# Palo Alto PA-4020 cannot connect to terminal through Serial to USB

Tags: terminal, serial, palo-alto-networks

I have a PA-4020 that I messed up the configuration on, and I am trying to do a factory reset.  I went ahead and ordered a few different serial to USB cables, and cannot connect through a Mac App Called Serial, PuttyTel (Windows) or Mac Terminal.  I set it to the palo alto recommended settings of https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/docs/DOC-2124 , but still can't seem to connect.  The USB device is detected, and the terminal opens without error, but you can't type any text or see anything.  I have tried rebooting the router several times.  Is there any other way to do a factory reset without the serial interface?  If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try both a normal and a null-modem cable?

Comment: I just ordered a null. We'll see if it works.

Comment: The answer is to get a null modem cable.  Thank you Ward for your help.  I got the startech ICUSB232FTN for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When troubleshooting anything with serial connections, try a null modem cable.  You mentioned a Startech USB to null modem cable, which makes sense, but you could also have gotten [a null-modem adapter, in DB9 or 25 and whatever gender you needed.](http://www.startech.com/ca/Search?search_term=null%20modem%20adapter)